# UTF-8 Encoding with internet explorer %u20AC to &euro;

Tags: php, internet-explorer, encoding, utf-8, tinymce

I'm currently using TinyMCE as html editor for users of my CMS.
Somehow the euro symbol (€) is converted to %u20AC by IE (any).

After a short search I found [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm). It gives a lot for different encodings for the UTF-8 euro symbol, but not %u20AC, with the percentage icon.

I have given the proper headers for UTF-8, so I gues IE is just being rude doing things its own way...

Is there a PHP function that can catch this strange encoding and put it to normal htmlentity (hex,decimal or named). I could just `string_replace()` this single problem symbol, but I'd rather fix all possible conflicts at once.

Or should I simply replace `%u` with `&#x` disabling normal usage of %u?

Comment: Where do you keep the symbol? In DB? Or directly in php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%u20AC` is Unicode-encoded data for `€` which is generated by *JavaScript `escape()` function* <sup>[*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape), [*ECMA262*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers.html#sec-escape-string)</sup> to UTF8 for server-side processing.

Standard PHP [`urldecode()`](https://php.net/urldecode) can not deal with it (it is a non-standard *percent encoding* <sup>[*WP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)</sup>), so you need to use an extended routine:

```php
/**
 * @param string $string unicode and ulrencoded string
 * @return string decoded string
 */
function utf8_urldecode($string) {
    $string = preg_replace(
        "/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i",
        "&#x\\1;",
        urldecode($string)
    );
    return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Also check if you can configure this behaviour for your TinyMCE.

---

**References**

- [`preg_replace()`](https://php.net/preg_replace) - Regular expression search and replace
- [`urldecode()`](https://php.net/urldecode) - Decode URL-encoded string
- [`html_entity_decode()`](https://php.net/html_entity_decode) - Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters (here: `&x20AC` -> `€` `U+20AC EURO SIGN` / `\u{20AC}` / `\xE2\x82\xAC` / `\342\202\254`)
- [3v4l.org example of this answer in action](https://3v4l.org/5bUMS)

Comment: Thank you very much! Any idea why this doesn't happen in Firefox?

Comment: @Webscrabbler: Nope. It's probably related to TinyMCE, I have no clue why TinyMCE want's to escape that character anyway.

Comment: The function works, but I'm getting 'html_entity_decode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($flags) of type int is deprecated'. How to fix that?

Comment: @JeroenSteen: Thanks for asking. Basically to use the correct default value of the `$flags` parameter, compare https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode . This is just a pretty old answer and it hasn't seen `declare(strict_types=1);` nor anthing PHP 8. Will update the answer for PHP 5.4+ and compatible with _strict types_.

Answer (score 0):

`20AC` it's the HEX code of euro, so you can slove this problem easly just in your html file in stead of usign `€` try to use this code `&#8364;`

Comment: My customers use the TinyMCE platform and don't know what unicode is. They need to be able to simply use € in IE

Comment: Sorry but i dont know other way, try to check TinyMCE Menu you will find it probly ?